# KeyErrror: "parameter"

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

So I'm trying to implement a GUI in PyQT using a table, but for some reason I keep getting the error KeyError:"Parameter",
The dictionary uses variables from a decoded bin file that has data i would like to access an use

I'm very confused as i see no way forward, any help would be appreciated.
Below is my code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class DictionaryTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, headers):
        super(DictionaryTableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self._headers = headers

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # Look up the key by header index.
            column = index.column()
            column_key = self._headers[column]
            return self._data[index.row()][column_key]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The length of our headers.
        return len(self._headers)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is the index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._headers[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(section)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        with open("C:\\Ptests\\asdf\\bikeparametereditor\\uploaddomainobject.bin", 'rb') as file:
            bytes2 = file.read()
            # Read & Assign to variables

            serialNumber = bytes2[0x1b:0x1b + 15].decode("utf-8")

            frameNumber = bytes2[0x2a:0x3b].decode("utf-8")

            productionDate = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x3b:0x3e], byteorder="little")

            hardwareVersion = bytes2[0x3f:0x49].decode("utf-8")

            ssDO_KEY_LOCK = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x49:0x49], byteorder="little")

            coreDataVersion = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x00:0x02], byteorder="little")

            coreCRC = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x03:0x06], byteorder="little")

            coreTimeStamp = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x07:0x09], byteorder="little")

            coreAddrIndex = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x09:0x11], byteorder="little")

            coreSize = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x20:0x21], byteorder="little")

            coreWriteCounter = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x21:0x22], byteorder="little")

            corefailCounter = int.from_bytes(bytes2[0x22:0x23], byteorder="little")

        data = [
            {"serialNumber": serialNumber,
             "frameNumber": frameNumber,
             "productionDate": productionDate,
             "hardwareVersion": hardwareVersion,
             "coreDataVersion": coreDataVersion,
             "coreCRC": coreCRC,
             "coreTimeStamp": coreTimeStamp,
             "coreAddrIndex": coreAddrIndex,
             "coreSize": coreSize,
             "coreWriteCounter": coreWriteCounter,
             "corefailCounter": corefailCounter,
             "ssDO_KEY_LOCK": ssDO_KEY_LOCK}
        ]

        headers = ["parameter", "value"]

        self.model = DictionaryTableModel(data, headers)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)




app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your data very clearly does not have the required structure. It is a list containing a single dict which does not a have any keys named "parameter". What exactly do you expect the table to look like?

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks for the reply. Yes i figured out my mistake. i needed to to add a parameter key in the dictionary and then link it. 

Somtimes it's right in your face but you just don't see it. Thank you very much